# Will 1000BASE-LX autonegotiate to work with 100BASE-FX

Tags: ethernet, fiber

We have existing equipment that uses 100BASE-FX (multi-mode fiber).  Will it work with 1000BASE-LX (also multi-mode) through autonegotiation?  Virtually everything I found on the web about autonegotiation was for copper interefaces.

This question is different from [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/54751/upgrading-from-100base-fx-to-1000base-sx-fiber) which covers the fiber.

EDIT: 2/8/11: changed gigabit to -LX so both are 1300 nm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not by design, though it wouldn't be hard to design a NIC/module that could handle both but you'd need to let us know what equipment is at the gig end to allow us to help you on that.

Comment: Some (unknown) proprietary equipment.  My question is more about does the standard support autonegotiation?  Require it?

Comment: No, the encoding is wildly different for a start.

Comment: I think what Chopper means to say is that equipment that supports 1000BaseSX doesn't necessarily support 100BaseFX, it's possible the equipment supports both, but certainly not all cards do.

Answer (score 4):

The optical wavelengths of the two standards you mentioned, 100Base-FX and 1000Base-SX, are incompatible with each other.

100Base-FX uses a 1300 nm near-infrared (NIR) light wavelength, while 1000Base-SX uses a 770 to 860 nanometer, near infrared (NIR) light wavelength.